# How can I customize jquery dialog box?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get and customize a dialog box in jQuery. How to do I change the color in dialog box title bar ?

I had the jQuery code as,

```
$("#dialog").dialog("open");    
var state = true;
if (state) {
    $("#dialog").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FFEDB8",
        color: "black",                
    });

$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });

$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({   
        title: "Acquaintance Details",
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Invite: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }               
        }
    });
});
```

and then html code as

```
<div id="dialog">
    <p>Are u want add </p>
    <form>
       <fieldset>
            <label id="fristname"></label>
            <br><label id="lastname"></label>
            <br><label id="mobilenumber"></label>
       </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: if you need a specific answer add http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Either do it manually with your own css, or use the themebuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example.

Create a class in your css *(say youCustomClass)* with your desired styles add it to the dialog title using the below jQuery code.

```
$(function () {
     $("#msg").dialog({
        open: function () {
           $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass("youCustomClass");
                          }        
          });    
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just style the dialog box to your requirement.

Just check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96RVj/) which i created for the sake of demo.

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar
{
 background-color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

or try adding this to your style